# php loop show current year data if not found instead of skiping

Tags: php, loops, foreach

So I have a loop within a loop both have year data and I'm trying to figure out how to show current year (2021) data if years don't match or exist on loop instead of using continue to skip the entry, any ideas or solutions are appreciated.

LIVE CODE: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b7cbef0613636aa41a41a7d5f283a2569ece9cb0

```
$dates = [
    ['date_starts'=>'2021-03-22'],
    ['date_starts'=>'2022-04-22'],
    ['date_starts'=>'2023-05-22']
];
              
foreach( $dates as $dt ){
    $start_date = $dt['date_starts'];
    
    $rates_results = [
        ['price'=>255,'year'=>'2021'],
        ['price'=>300,'year'=>'2023']
    ];

    $rateIDs = [];
    if ($rates_results) {
        foreach ($rates_results as $rates) {
            if(date("Y", strtotime($start_date)) !== ''.$rates['year'].''){
                continue;
            }
            
            $rateIDs [] = [
                'year' => $rates['year'],
                'price' => $rates['price']
            ];
        }
    }
    print_r($rateIDs);
}
```

So this is the OUTPUT I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2021
            [price] => 255
        )

)
Array
(
)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2023
            [price] => 300
        )

)
```

And this is the result I'm looking for:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2021
            [price] => 255
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2021
            [price] => 255
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2023
            [price] => 300
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the answers and the comments to them, it seems perhaps you are looking for something like this:

```php
$dates = [
    ['date_starts'=>'2021-03-22'],
    ['date_starts'=>'2022-04-22'],
    ['date_starts'=>'2023-05-22']
];

$current_year = date('Y');
              
foreach ($dates as $dt) {
    
    $rates_results = [
        ['price'=>255, 'year'=>'2021'],
        ['price'=>200, 'year'=>'2021'],
        ['price'=>300, 'year'=>'2023']
    ];
    
    // get the year from the start date. Since it's in YYYY-MM-DD format
    // we can just use substr
    $start_year = substr($dt['date_starts'], 0, 4);
    
    // find matching years in $rates_results
    $rate_keys = array_keys(array_column($rates_results, 'year'), $start_year);
    
    // any matches?
    if (empty($rate_keys)) {
        // no, use the values from the current year instead
        $rate_keys = array_keys(array_column($rates_results, 'year'), $current_year);
    }
    
    // get the actual rates
    $code = 1;
    $rates = array();
    foreach ($rate_keys as $key) {
        $rates[] = [
            'custom' => $code,
            'price' => $rates_results[$key]['price'],
            'year' => $rates_results[$key]['year']
            ];
    }
    
    // output the rates
    print_r($rates);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [price] => 255
            [year] => 2021
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [price] => 200
            [year] => 2021
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [price] => 255
            [year] => 2021
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [price] => 200
            [year] => 2021
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [price] => 300
            [year] => 2023
        )

)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/9HZL8)

Comment: Hey nick thanks for sharing code, wondering if u could check original code and see if it makes sense to you, in RATES LOGIC you cans see the `continue` line that basically skips if no match and result is empty array [] so instead i'm looking to print current year info instead of empty array [SANDBOX LINK](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/18a93e5d256e5abd4b2e0cecc7e855fe6a66a526)

Comment: @Ered No worries - I'm glad it was helpful. The code does print out the current year (2021) instead of an empty array for 2022.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're overcomplicating this having nested for loops. In reality you have a `dates` array and a `rates` array and you want to cross reference one against the other?

To do this what you need to do is loop through the `dates` array and then use PHPs `array_*` functions to find the key for the specific year; then if the nothing was found then use the current year.

```
$dates = [
    ['date_starts'=>'2021-03-22'],
    ['date_starts'=>'2022-04-22'],
    ['date_starts'=>'2023-05-22']
];

$rates_results = [
    ['price'=>255,'year'=>'2021'],
    ['price'=>300,'year'=>'2023']
];
$rate_year_array = array_column($rates_results, "year");             // Extract year "column" from $rates_results


foreach ($dates as $date_row) {
    $search_year  = date("Y", strtotime($date_row["date_starts"]));  // Get the year to look up from the date supplied
    $rate_key     = array_search($search_year, $rate_year_array);    // Search the "year" array and get the key for the current year
                                                                     // If not found then the value will be (bool) false
    
    if ($rate_key === false) {                                       // Check if the key was found
        $rate_key = array_search(date("Y"), $rate_year_array);       // If not find the key for the current year
    }

    // Output the date to an array
    $rateIDs[] = [
        'year'  => $rates_results[$rate_key]["year"],
        'price' => $rates_results[$rate_key]["price"],
    ];

}

print_r($rateIDs);  // Print the array
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2021
            [price] => 255
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2021
            [price] => 255
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2023
            [price] => 300
        )

)
```

Comment: in example I give a simple example, but original code is a bit more complicated, any chance u can also give an example if I use nested for loops?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood correctly, but here goes...

Initialize a `$matched` variable before the loop, and set it to `true` if there is a match (to know there's no need to add current year data).

If there was no match, search the data array (`$rates_results`) to see if the current year exists, if so, add it to the result

```
<?php
$dates = [
    ['date_starts'=>'2021-03-22'],
    ['date_starts'=>'2022-04-22'],
    ['date_starts'=>'2023-05-22']
];
              
foreach( $dates as $dt ){
    $start_date = $dt['date_starts'];
    
    $rates_results = [
        ['price'=>255,'year'=>'2021'],
        ['price'=>300,'year'=>'2023']
    ];

    $rateIDs = [];
    if ($rates_results) {
        $matched = false;
        
        foreach ($rates_results as $rates) {
            if(date("Y", strtotime($start_date)) !== ''.$rates['year'].'') {
                continue;
            }
            
            $matched = true;
            $rateIDs[] = [
                'year' => $rates['year'],
                'price' => $rates['price']
            ];
        }
        
        if ($matched === false) {
            $key = array_search(date('Y'), array_column($rates_results, 'year'));
            if ($key !== false) {
                $rateIDs[] = [
                    'year' => $rates_results[$key]['year'],
                    'price' => $rates_results[$key]['price']
                ];
            }
        }
    }
    print_r($rateIDs);
}
```

Comment: ev0tix, if there's 2 entries in with same year in `$rates_results = [
        ['price'=>255,'year'=>'2021'],
        ['price'=>200,'year'=>'2021'],
        ['price'=>300,'year'=>'2023']
    ];` it should also output both and below it outputs only one any thoughts on this, check online example [link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ff8ec51eaca01c022eb283e7aa441d4284dd030c )

Comment: Then you should loop over $rates_results again to search for multiple values of current year. [Sandbox code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6934fc394615f513009bccb4079004a403a831d1)

Comment: ev0tix, now last question  what if I have custom code inside the first loop, instead of duplicating it on next loop is there any other way to do it? [SAND BOX LINK](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d43249b52958b2737d930cc8cf7342b1723be6b7)

Comment: I need some more details to understand it; why is the custom code in the `$rates_results` loop, where will it come from? is it going to change each loop?
With a lot of assumptions, which might be incorrect, you can define it outside of the loop `$code = null;` (next to `$matched = false;`) and then use it later in the next loop, which will have `$code` holding the value from the first loop, or `null` if there was no match -- which actually means there won't ever be a value on the next loop since it's only reaching it when there's no match :-)

Comment: Unless you put `$code` before the `if` condition and then it will have a value even if there is no match.

Comment: ok I get it it all depends on the structure im using, any way I will add the original code and see if it makes sense to you, in RATES LOGIC you can see the `continue` line that basically skips if no match and result is empty array [] so instead I'm looking to print current year info instead of empty array  [SANDBOX LINK](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/18a93e5d256e5abd4b2e0cecc7e855fe6a66a526)

Comment: ev0tix thanks for ur help, @Nick posted the logic I was looking for, and I understand that without info it's hard to generate code, I appreciate ur help and  time

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $dates = [
    ['date_starts'=>'2021-03-22'],
    ['date_starts'=>'2022-04-22'],
    ['date_starts'=>'2023-05-22']
];
              
foreach( $dates as $dt ){
    $start_date = $dt['date_starts'];
    
    $rates_results = [
        ['price'=>255,'year'=>'2021'],
        ['price'=>300,'year'=>'2022'],
        ['price'=>300,'year'=>'2023']
    ];

    $rateIDs = [];
    if ($rates_results) {
        foreach ($rates_results as $rates) {
            if(date("Y", strtotime($start_date)) !== ''.$rates['year'].''){
             
                continue;
                
            }
           
                $rateIDs [] = [
                'year' => $rates['year'],
                'price' => $rates['price']
            ];
            
            
           
        }
    }
    print_r($rateIDs);
}
```